# SQL return distinct results and a column that does not have to be distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have  a table with a bunch of columns but I only need 5 columns returned from the table they are:

```
Name | Charge Code | Charge Amount | Modifier | Date
```

I am looking to return the fields based on only Distinct Name, Charge Codes, Charge Amounts and Modifiers. The Date can be the latest Date that the record exists. How can I do this?

Currently I have:

```
Select 
    Name, Charge_code, Charge_amount, Modifier, Date
From 
    Table1
group by 
    Name, Charge_code, Charge_amount, Modifier
```

However when I do this it tells me the Date is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or group by. I Don't want to include the Date in the group by function cause then it will return a bunch of extraneous rows that are not necessary. But I do want the date to show the latest date that that person charged that amount.

I have also tried

```
Select 
    Date, Distinct Name, Charge_Code, Charge_amount, Modifier
From 
    Table 1
```

Any ideas would be helpful I am new.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this as well, simple and easy

```
Select name, 
    charge_code, 
    charge_amount, 
    modifier, 
    max(date) date
From table1
Group by name, charge_code, charge_amount, modifier
```

Comment: This is perfectly valid for this special case (should be optimal, in fact), but I still would encourage using row_number() - it should be just as efficient for this query, and is infinitely more flexible. E.g. if you wanted to get some other random column value *from the same row/record* that has the `max(date)` value, you can easily do it with row_number() but not with a simple group by.  Just sayin...

Comment: I agree this one is simpler to understand for me a beginner to know what is going on. The other seemed to work as well but this one I can at least speak to what its doing alittle better. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The typical way is to use `row_number()`:

```
select Name, ChargeCode, ChargeAmount, Modifier, Date
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Name, ChargeCode, ChargeAmount, Modifier
                                order by date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This looks to be a very different setup than I was expecting. How efficient is this as this is a very big table? I have never used seqnum or row_number in my queries before. Please review the updated post as well and see if that is still making senese

Comment: @TaylorD . . . The performance should be better than a `group by`.

Comment: @TaylorD the syntax for row_number() and other analytic functions takes some getting used to, but I assure you it is as efficient and often much more efficient for the query optimizer than any other equivalent (at least most of the time). If you get used to it, analytic functions will *greatly* increase the quality of your code, assuming you also have a good indexing strategy, compare execution plans to prove out options, etc.

Comment: and do I still do the t.* even if I have other columns I do not need to use for this?

Comment: @TaylorD . . . There is no need to avoid that.  SQL Server will be efficient about selecting only the columns used in the query, and the outer `select` restricts the columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct  main.Name, main.ChargeCode, main.ChargeAmount, main.Modifier,  
                 b.Date
FROM Table1  as main
Outer Apply (Select Top 1 Date
            from Table1 as sub
            where main.Name = sub.Name and main.ChargeCode = sub.ChargeCode and   main.ChargeAmount = sub.ChargeAmount and main.Modifier = sub.Modifier
            Order by sub.Date desc
             ) b
```